# MySQL How to Insert Minute Values Like '00:65:00' (Larger than 59 minutes and 59 seconds?

Tags: mysql, datetime, time, datetime-format

MySQL - I'm trying import minute values into a Time column which are stored like '00:55:00', '00:20:00', '00:65:00', '00:200:00'.  It works fine for all values <= '00:59:59' but when I do '00:60:00' or greater I get an error "Incorrect time value."

You can see what i mean if you try to do "Select Time('00:59:59')" and "Select Time('00:60:00')".  The first one works but the second one returns NULL.  How can I import time values larger than "00:59:59" in MySQL.

Comment: Why can't you use "01:00:00" instead of "00:60:00"?

Comment: I have thousands of values coming from a CSV file and stored in the format of minutes.

Comment: So you may use `minutes div 60` as hours and `minutes mod 60` as minutes in your time column.

Comment: Why don't you convert them before inserting them?

Comment: How would I convert them in MySQL?

Comment: Turn them into seconds and save an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out a way to convert minutes and seconds to the proper format:

Convert minutes to int, multiply by 60 and add then add that to the seconds (which is converted to an int also)

```
SEC_TO_TIME(CAST(SUBSTR(MIN,1,2) AS SIGNED)*60 + CAST(SUBSTR(MIN,4,2) AS SIGNED));
```

Converts `60:25` to `01:00:25`.